# Exception Index Out Of Bounds when using deleteCharAt with StringBuilder

Tags: scala

I want to delete duplicate char in my string with using deleteCharAt method but it's giving me an exception

```
def removeDuplicate(str: String): String={ 
   var sb = new StringBuilder(str);
  for(i <-0 until str.length ){
      for(z <- i+1 until str.length ){
        if(str(i)==str(z)){         
            sb.deleteCharAt(i);
        }
      }
  }
   return sb.toString;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggested, when `i = str.length - 1`, `z = str.length` which is out of index. And there is another problem with your code, which is you are removing character from a string while looping through it. It is usually not a good practice to do so since the string length changes every time you delete a character, and you need to keep track of that. An alternative and more intuitive way is to build a new string and add only characters that have not appeared in the new string:

```
def removeDuplicate(str: String):String = {
  var sb = ""
  for(i <- 0 until str.length) {
    if(! (sb contains str(i))) {
      sb += str(i)
    }}
  sb
}

scala> removeDuplicate("abbccssds")
res13: String = abcsd

scala> removeDuplicate("abbeedsff")
res14: String = abedsf

scala> removeDuplicate("abbeedsffgg")
res15: String = abedsfg
```